# What characters should be avoided in a file name on a website

Tags: url, special-characters, filenames

I upload many PDF files to a webserver and link them to the website. Sometimes the file names have non-English characters resulting in 404 error and browsers displays strange characters in the address bar where the accented characters should be. What other types of characters should be avoided? For example is it a bad idea to link to a file with an "&" or spaces in the name? We use repliweb and I was told it crashes on certain atypical characters, can anyone verify or refute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should really, always (not just on servers - it's generally a good practice for the sake of portability between different OSes and languages) avoid filenames that contain any characters which are not:

- Alphanumeric English characters (a...z, A...Z, 0...9)
- Underscore (_)
- And maybe a hyphen (-)

Comment: I guess for the accented characters I will replace them with whatever character they look most like in English, unless someone has a better idea?

Comment: @Celeritas that's fine, it's how we do it in my language.